# "while" loop not ending when it should

Tags: c++, c

Here's the very basic code. The loop will start, even if the condition is false, and it won't end.

```
        int oldpick = 6;
        int pick = rand() % 5;

        while (pick = oldpick){
            pick = rand() % 5;
        }
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, `rand() % 5` will never equal 6

Comment: @chris They are. I'm still new to c++ and I wrote an assignment instead of a check-for-equality. My bad.

Comment: @vanjoe this is only a part of my code.

Comment: Advice: Push the compiler warning level to a maximum, treat all warnings as error and disable (ridiculous) warnings after spotting these.

Answer (score 2):

```
pick = oldpick
```

This assignes the value of `oldpick` to `pick`, and then enters the loop. I think you wanted `==`

```
while (pick == oldpick){
```

Also, this line:

```
pick = rand() % 5;
```

will not give a number higher than 4, so the condition could never be realised, even with `==`

All of this could have been seen if warnings had been activated when compiling.

Comment: Ouch, didn't see that at all. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple typographical error in your while loop condition...

`while (pick = oldpick)` should be `while (pick == oldpick)` for equals or `while (pick != oldpick)` for not equals.

Plus, `pick` will never ever equal 6 as `6 % 5 == 5`

Comment: Funny, "simple typographical error" appears verbatim in the close reasons.

Comment: @chris I cannot vote to close yet. So what else is there? I would agree that it should be closed.

Comment: Waiting is always an option. It's almost there.

Comment: @chris roger, will do that next time :)